# MongoDB: use of $nin and $ne operator

Tags: mongodb

1. 

```
{
  "cuisine": {
    $nin: [
      "American",
      "Chinees"
    ]
  }
}
```

2. 

```
{
  "$and": [
    {
      "cuisine": {
        $ne: "American "
      }
    },
    {
      "cuisine": {
        $ne: "Chinees"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

In mongodb, how is the 1st code is different from 2nd one? Here, `cuisine` is a field and `American` and `Chinees` are its value.
Also, can you tell me the difference between `$ne` operator and `$nin` operator?

Answer (score 0):

There is a space after `American` in the second query.